# Confusion on call Java Interface method

Tags: java, interface

Let's say I have an interface **A**, defined as follows:

```
public interface A {
    public void a();
}
```

It includes a method called **a**.

I have a class which implements this interface and it has only one method:

```
public class AImpl implements A {
    @Override
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("Do something");
    }
}
```

Q: If, in the main class I call the interface method, will it call the implementation belonging to the class which implements the interface?

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A aa;
    aa.a();
}
```

Will this print "Do something"?

Comment: The left side is always just a slot where an object can go. As Johan said, you need to actually "put" an object there by creating one with `new`.

Comment: Please try to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to describe your problem. And include the error messages you get. The interface won't compile and the main method will throw a `NullPointerException`. Other than that, your question is valid and should be answered by my answer below.

Comment: @JayZhang: Don't forget to accept (checkmark) the best answer. So everybody knows that the problem is solved.

Comment: This works for me thanks. But is this the standard way of using `service` interface classes and `serviceimpl` classes?

Answer (score 32):

```
A aa = new AImpl();
aa.a();
```

*Here your reference variable is interface `A` type But actual `Object` is `AImpl`*.

> When you define a new interface, you are defining a new reference data
>   type. You can use interface names anywhere you can use any other data
>   type name. If you define a reference variable whose type is an
>   interface, any object you assign to it must be an instance of a class
>   that implements the interface.

Read more on [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html)

A Interface reference can hold Object of AImpl as it implements the A interface.

Answer (score 26):

It depends on the runtime type of the object. See:

This is your interface:

```
public interface A {
  public void a();
}
```

And this is your class:

```
public class AImpl implements A {
    public void a() {
       println("I am AImpl");
    }
}
```

There is another implementation:

```
public class AnotherAImpl implements A {
    public void a() {
       println("I am another AImpl");
    }
}
```

So have a look at the this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  A aa;
  aa = new AImpl();
  aa.a(); // prints I am AImpl
  aa = new AnotherAImpl();
  aa.a(); // now it prints I am another AImpl
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am now understand

Comment: Example isn't another way to teach, it is the only way to teach (Albert Einstein).
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke the routine on the actual `AImpl` object

```
A aa = new AImpl();
aa.a();
```

which here is equivalent to following

```
AImpl aa = new AImpl();
aa.a();
```

Your sample will raise an error since you're trying invoke a method on an uninitalized object.

Comment: Not equal in the sense of OO Design. If you have that interface, you need to use it to prove it's existence.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably find this out by running the code yourself.

Currently you will get a `NullPointerException` because you haven't assigned anything to the variable `aa`. Changing your code to the following will invoke the method and output the text:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    A aa = new AImpl();
    aa.a();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. I will not.

You have declared a variable. You should initialze it first with instance of an object in this case your class `AImpl`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  A aa = new AImp();
  aa.a();
}
```